# I am unable to calculate the probabilities of case (i) and (ii) in the question shared below. Can someone help me calculate both with an explanation??

Tags: probability

Two bundles of cash as a prize are HIDDEN behind the spinning wheel in consecutive slots as shown in the picture.
[The image shows the front and back sides of a spinning wheel. The wheel is divided into 8 equal portions numbered from 1-8. The back of the wheel shows that the prizes are behind the numbers 6 and 7. The back side is not visible to the player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7dx8.png)

If on the first spin, a person does not win a prize, they get to choose one of the following options:

(i) Another, last chance to spin the wheel.
(ii) Choose the contents of the NEXT slot. [Ex. choose 1, if they land on 8; or choose 4 if they land on 3]

Wilma spun the wheel and lost. Which of the following actions has a higher probability of winning the prize for Wilma?

A. Choosing option (i)
B. Choosing option (ii)
C. Choosing either options since the probability of winning, in either case, is the same.
D. Choosing either options since the given information is insufficient to make a decision.

Comment: Welcome here! What did you try? If you show your efforts to solve the problem, it will motivate people to help you. For example, what can you conclude from "Wilma lost"?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding. I concluded that on the first spin, she landed on either, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 8. That is when she did not get a prize and had to choose one of the options. For option (i) I know that it is independent of the first spin and the probability can be calculated as 2/8, where two are the slots on the spinner behind which there are prizes and 8 are the total slots.

Comment: For option (ii) however, I am unsure how the probability will be calculated - This is what I think - This is not independent of the first spin. She will only choose the next slot to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 8 because she will only be picking (i) or (ii) if she has lost. So the probability I think will be 1/6, where 1 is if she lands on slot 5 (because the next slot 6 has a prize) and 6 is the slots that she would have landed on without getting a prize. I am unsure about (ii) though.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. You should edit it into the question. The correct answer is A. The question is a bit odd since it asks about the highest probability and we have enough information to answer, while Wilma does not (if the prizes were behind slots $6$ and $8$, for example, she'd better choose option (ii)).

Comment: Thank you so much! Noted. The way I imagine this is that I am organizing the game and I know/ am calculating the odds. Wilma doesn't and shouldn't or it would defeat the purpose of the game. Similar to if I was a dealer and Wilma were playing a game of cards. Does that make sense? Also, would it be correct to calculate the combined probability of case (i) as 6/8 x 2/8 and case (ii) as 6/8 x 1/6?, where 6/8 is the probability of her ending up on a slot behind which there is no prize in the first spin?

Comment: Please don't make essential parts of the question dependent on images; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem/34123#34123.

Comment: Thank you Joriki. Noted! That is why added alt text as descriptive as possible. Will keep in mind in the future.

Comment: @Nikhil: I am not sure what "combined probability" means. $6/8\times 2/8$ is the probability of the event "Wilma loses at 1st trial and win at the 2d trial while choosing method (i)"